# Spectrum of the Magnetic Stark Hamiltonians $H(\mu,\epsilon)$

Tags: reference-request, sp.spectral-theory

I am looking for a document where I can find a proof the spectrum of the of the Magnetic Stark
Hamiltonians $H(\mu,\epsilon)=\big(D_x-\mu y)^2+D^2_y+\epsilon x+V(x,y)$ cited on the article below for $\epsilon\not=0$ see equation $(1.2)$ in

http://www.hrpub.org/download/20140105/MS6-13401691.pdf

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A unitary transformation $\tilde{H}=e^{-i\mu xy}He^{i\mu xy}$ will transform the Hamiltonian into 
$$\tilde{H}(\mu,\epsilon)=D_x^2+(D_y+\mu x)^2+\epsilon x+V(x,y),\;\;D_\nu=-i\partial/\partial\nu,$$
so for $V\equiv 0$ this is a harmonic oscillator with eigenfunctions $\psi_{k,n}(x,y)=e^{iky}\phi_n(x)$ and eigenvalues
$$E_n(k)=(2n+1)\mu-k\epsilon/\mu-\tfrac{1}{4}(\epsilon/\mu)^2,\;\;n=0,1,2,\ldots,\;\;k\in\mathbb{R}.$$
This spectrum extends from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, see the plot of $E_n$ versus $k$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$ (at $\mu=1=\epsilon$).

[image]

The effect of a localised potential $V$ can be accounted for in perturbation theory, it cannot change the range of the spectrum. Incidentally, this is the spectrum of an electron in perpendicular magnetic and electric fields.

Comment: So, its spectrum is purely punctual.

Comment: Is $\psi_{k,n}(x,y)=e^{iky}\phi_n(x)\in L^2(\Bbb{R}^2)$?, if it is the spectrum of the operator in question is ponctual. But it seems that $\psi_{k,n}(x,y)=e^{iky}\phi_n(x)\not\in L^2(\Bbb{R}^2)$ so its spectrum is continuous

Comment: certainly, it's a continuous spectrum, I added a plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i have another question, Since $H(\mu,\epsilon)$ is self adjoint then its spectrum is  in $\Bbb{R}$, for the inverse we must build a weyl's sequence for $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$. For instance if $T$ acting in $L^2(\Bbb{R}^2)$ is an operator such that $T(f)=a (f),\quad a\in \Bbb{R}$ this does not imply that $a\in \sigma(T)$

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741254/no-weyl-sequence?noredirect=1#comment5656417_2741254